# setAllowedOverMetered vs setAllowedNetworkTypes

Tags: android

The documentation of `setAllowedNetworkTypes(int)` now has this:

> As of N, setting only the NETWORK_WIFI flag here is equivalent to calling setAllowedOverMetered(boolean) with false.

Which makes sense but now begs the question, what is the case before N?
So for example, prior to N a request with `setAllowedNetworkTypes(NETWORK_WIFI)` was **not equal** to `setAllowedOverMetered(false)`?

If not, then how and why would they add the comment about it being equal starting from N.